# Abstract class implementation not working in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class

I am trying to implement an abstract class in python. Following is my code:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Vehicle:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, miles):
        self.miles = miles        

    def sale_price(self):
        """Return the sale price for this vehicle as a float amount."""
        if self.miles > 10000:
            return 20.0  
        return 5000.0 / self.miles

    @abstractmethod
    def vehicle_type(self):
        """"Return a string representing the type of vehicle this is."""
        pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    def vehicle_type(self):
        return 'car'

def main():
    veh = Vehicle(10)
    print(veh.sale_price())
    print(veh.vehicle_type())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This executes perfectly without giving any error. Is the main() not supposed to throw an error that I `Can't instantiate abstract class Base with abstract methods value`? What am I doing wrong? I am using python 3.4

Comment: In Python 3 metaclass is not defined this way.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary can you please show me the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the Python 2.x method of defining `metaclass` , For Python 3.x you need to do the following -

```
class Vehicle(metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

This was introduced through [PEP 3115 - Metaclasses in Python 3000](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/)

---

The issue occurs because for using `@abstractmethod` decorator it is required that the class’s metaclass be ABCMeta or be derived from it. As given in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod)

> **@abc.abstractmethod**
>
> A decorator indicating abstract methods.
>
> **Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or is derived from it.**

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will accept the answer in 6 minutes (as soon as SO allows me to). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U  include a raise exception in **init** method to use in Python2.x

```
class Vehicle:
   __metaclass__=abc.ABCMeta
   def __init__(self):
      raise NotImplemetedError('The class cannot be instantiated')
   @abstractmethod
   def vehicletype(self):
       pass
```

This will not allow the abstract class to be instantiated.